# Change the language from app?

Tags: android

How can I change the language for phone from an android app? Can you give me some example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phone-level language control is typically done using restricted interfaces: as far as I am aware there is no direct control from an app as part of the public Android interface.

Your best bet would be to use an Intent to open up the language picker. The Intent filter is:

```
<intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <action android:name="android.settings.LOCALE_SETTINGS" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE_LAUNCH" />
             </intent-filter>
```

So something like this should work:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
i.startActivity();
```

And then the user can pick their language from there.